# How do I run Titanfall in a custom screen resolution?

Tags: titanfall

It's no secret that [Titanfall is a Source game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanfall#Development).

I like to play my games in a specific resolution in windowed mode, but that resolution isn't supported by all games. For those that don't, I can often set the exact width and height to start the game in using its launch options.

For Source games like Team Fortress 2, Portal, and The Stanley Parable, the obvious solution is:

```
-windowed -w <width> -h <height>
```

But Titanfall seems to either ignore the `-w` and `-h` options entirely, or resize the window to an arbitrary (but preset) size such as 1024x768. I tried `-width` and `-height` respectively, to no avail.

Does Titanfall's version of Source ignore those two options entirely? Is there another way around it?

Comment: Note: this was posted during the beta period, but it looks like the issue is still in the final game.

Comment: It seems like the game only really supports standard resolutions.  If you edit the config files directly, it will always seem to snap at the usual `1024x768` or `1280x720` for smaller resolutions.